# How to insert default values record for a specific new primary key record?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table named myTable with several columns which for some of them there is a default value and for the rest of the columns NULL is a possible and an acceptable value.

There is a primary key named pkVariable and the rest of the columns named column2, column3, column4 and column5.
column2 and column3 are configured to get default values 0 and 1 respectively and configured as NOT NULL.
column4 and column5 has no default values but they are set to have NULL values as a possibility.

My question is, how do I insert a new "empty" record into the myTable. I mean, I would like to have in a new record in myTable the primary key value, the default value for column2 & column3 and NULL value for column4 and column5.

If pkVariable had a default value or was an IDENTITY I could do that:

```
INSERT INTO myTable DEFAULT VALUES;
```

buy I can't, 'cause pkVariable must get pkValue in the INSERT clause.

I can use:

```
INSERT INTO myTable VALUES (pkValue, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT);
```

and it works, but I would not like to be dependent on the number of columns.

Therefore, what is the correct syntax to achieve my goal?

I falsely thought I could do that:

```
INSERT INTO [myTable] ([pkVariable]) VALUES (pkValue) DEFUALT VALUES;
```

and thought of this direction:

```
WITH pkVariable = pkValue
INSERT INTO [myTable] DEFAULT VALUES;
```

any other suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

Simply do not include the columns that you want defaulted in your insert. It will use the defaults if the columns are not included.

```
MYTABLE
-PKColumn IDENTITY(1,1)
-Column1 VARCHAR DEFAULT 'ColumnValue'
-Column2 INT
```

Then, all you would need to do is this:

```
INSERT INTO MYTABLE (Column2) VALUES (123);
```

The row will be inserted as

```
1|'ColumnValue'|123
```

Notice how the defaults were all inserted

Answer (score 0):

If all of your columns allow nulls or have a default value and you don't want to specify any values on insert then try something like:

```
drop table #test
create table #test (id int identity, test varchar(10) default 'test' not null, 
                    test2 varchar (10) null, test3 int default 1 not null)

insert into #test (test)
values (default)

select * from #test
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a Sequence for your PK ID Column with the following command

`nextval('[name of your sequence]'::regclass)`

Then you can insert with `INSERT AS SELECT [whatever]`

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to say that you want to enter a record with a specific primary key, use this.

```
set identity_insert mytable on
insert into mytable (pkvariable) values (1)
set identity_insert mytable off
```

This assumes you are using an auto-increment identity for your primary key.